# Trying to write a for loop in R that adds values to a vector if a condition is satisfied

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement, vector

I was trying to define a vector called IQR that returns the values within the Inner quartile range of another vector(not in numerical order).

I have tried numerous iterations of

```
IQR <- function(y) for (i in seq_along(y)) { if ((i > quantile(y, 0.25)) && (i < quantile(y, 0.75))) {iqr <- c(i)} else {break}}
```

and

```
IQR <- vector('double', 0) for (i in seq_along(Vect)) {if ((i > quantile(y, 0.25)) && (i < quantile(y, 0.75))) {iqr <- vector(i)} else {break}}
```

where vect is a stand alone vector containing the values to test created from the df

Comment: Please share more details like what is the output

Answer (score 0):

Use the extraction operator `[]` to select elements of a vector that meet a condition

Something like this:

```
IQR <- function(y)  y[ y>quantile(y,0.25) & y<quantile(y,0.75) ]  
# read as 'y, where y is greater than the 25th centile of y and y is less than the 75th centile of y'

IQR(1:10)
[1] 4 5 6 7
```